# OutOfMemory Exception in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, memory-leaks, custom-adapter

basically I have a gridview, in which I show my products (from 10 or 20 up to 1K+ items) each item has a couple of custom textviews, and an Imageview.

I use ViewHolder pattern and also [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) library to load images asynchronously. I have no problem with showing items, speed or whatsoever, so I think it's safe to say that my getview function works quite nice, although I have one major problem which is with scrolling the gridview, up and down, my memory monitor only shows increase of course the increment rate depends on the item-view contents as when I commented the image loading part for example, the rate decreased.

what I guess is somehow the generated views are always staying in the memory and something prevents them from getting collected by the GC. 
although sometimes, when I scroll slowly GC comes and collects and memory gets free, but scrolling fast will always result in OOM, sooner or later.

my main question is that if I have a memory leak or not?! since the gc sometimes works (slow scrlling), and sometimes lets the app crashes with OOM Exception.

and clearly I hope to find out my problem and every little bit of help would be appreciated in advance.

xml of the fragment-layout which hosts the Gridview:

```
<GridView
      android:id="@+id/gv_Main"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
      android:animationCache="false"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:scrollingCache="false"
      android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
      />
```

my adapter(this extends CursorAdapter, although I have exactly same problem whit baseadapter as well):

```
public class ShygunInventoryGridCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    private Cursor cursor;
    private int numColumns;
    private int listItemId, listItemNoImageId, gridItemId;
    private String[] type;
    private String[] columnTitle;
    private int[] viewId;
    private String textTemp;
    private CyberSetting cyberSetting;
    private String unitDesc = "";
    private boolean isMain;
    private int size;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int thumbSize = 200;

    private File pic;

    private TPictureCatalog pictureCatalog;
    private TProductCatalog productCatalog;


    //private ViewGroup hostActivity;
    //int idTemp;

    private LayoutInflater cursorInflater;



    public ShygunInventoryGridCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        this.mContext = context;
        cursorInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //this.cursor = c;
        productCatalog=TProductCatalog.getInstance();
        cyberSetting=CyberSetting.getInstance();
    }




    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = cursorInflater.inflate( R.layout.listview_inventory_product_griditems, parent, false);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvAttachment = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_inventory_products_griditems_attachment);
        holder.imageCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagecount);
        holder.tvItemCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_inventory_products_griditems_ItemCode);
        holder.tvProductName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_inventory_products_griditems_Title);
        holder.tvPrice = (RialTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_inventory_products_griditems_Price);
        holder.tvRemain = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.tv_inventory_products_griditems_Remain);
        holder.btnMore =(com.rey.material.widget.Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_inventory_products_griditems_More);
        holder.btnPlus = (com.rey.material.widget.Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_inventory_products_griditems_addOne);

        view.setTag(holder);
        Log.d("CurAd","newView");
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        Log.d("CurAd","bindView");

        ViewHolder holder;


        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();





        holder.itemId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseColumnContent.COL_PRODUCT_ITEM_ID.toString()));
        TSimpleProduct tempProduct = productCatalog.getSimpleProductById(Integer.parseInt(holder.itemId));
        holder.itemGuId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseColumnContent.COL_PRODUCT_GUID.toString()));
        holder.tvItemCode.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseColumnContent.COL_PRODUCT_ITEMCODE.toString())));
        holder.tvProductName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseColumnContent.COL_PRODUCT_ITEMDESC.toString())));

        //Remain
        if (cyberSetting.getSettingValue(TCyberSettingKey.SHOWITEMREMAIN).equals("1")) {
            textTemp = (mContext.getString(R.string.restrictedInfo));
        } else {
            if (tempProduct.getDefaultUnitValue() == 2 && tempProduct.isUnitDependent()) {
                String titleRemain2 = DatabaseColumnContent.COL_PRODUCT_CURSOR_REMAIN2.toString();
                textTemp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(titleRemain2));
            }
            if (cyberSetting.getSettingValue(TCyberSettingKey.SHOWITEMREMAIN).equals("2")) {
                if (textTemp == null) {
                    textTemp = "0";
                }
                int t = Integer.parseInt(textTemp);
                if (t > 0) {
                    textTemp = mContext.getString(R.string.productAvailable);
                } else {
                    textTemp = mContext.getString(R.string.productUnAvailable);
                }
            }
        }
        holder.tvRemain.setText(textTemp);

        //Price
        String priceLevel = "0";
        try {
            Register register = Register.getInstance();
            priceLevel = register.getPriceLevel();
        } catch (NoDaoSetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(!priceLevel.equals("0"))
            textTemp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(priceLevel));
        else
            textTemp = "0.0";

        if (tempProduct.getDefaultUnitValue() == 2 && tempProduct.isUnitDependent()) {
            double price2;
            price2 = TLineItem.convertPrice1ToPrice2(Double.parseDouble(textTemp), tempProduct.isUnit1Bigger(), tempProduct.getUnitCoef());
            textTemp = TGeneralTools.ConvertDoubleToEnglishString(price2);
            if (tempProduct.getUnitDesc2() != null && !tempProduct.getUnitDesc2().equals(""))
                unitDesc = " (" + tempProduct.getCompleteUnitDesc2() + ")";
        } else {
            if (tempProduct.getUnitDesc1() != null && !tempProduct.getUnitDesc1().equals(""))
                unitDesc = " (" + tempProduct.getCompleteUnitDesc1() + ")";
        }
        holder.priceDef = textTemp;
        holder.tvPrice.setText(textTemp + unitDesc);

        holder.tvRemain.setText(holder.tvRemain.getText() + unitDesc);


        //image
        pictureCatalog = TPictureCatalog.getInstance();
        String defGuid = "";

        if (tempProduct.getHasAttachContent() >= 1 && pictureCatalog.isDownloadedAlbumAvailable()) {
            defGuid = pictureCatalog.getDefaultPictureGuid(holder.itemGuId);
            if (tempProduct.getHasAttachContent() == 1) {
                holder.imageCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.imageCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imageCount.setText(String.valueOf(tempProduct.getHasAttachContent()));
            }
        } else {
            holder.imageCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + FileAddressContent.APPLICATION_HOME_DIRECTORY
                + FileAddressContent.PICTURES_ROOT_DIRECTORY
                //+ FileAddressContent.PICTURES_THUMBS_DIRECTORY.toString()
                + defGuid + FileAddressContent.PICTURES_EXTENSION;
        pic = new File(filename);
        if (pic.exists())
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(pic)
                    .error(R.drawable.noimage)
                            //.placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                    .resize(thumbSize, thumbSize)
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(holder.tvAttachment);
        else
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.noimage)
                    .resize(thumbSize, thumbSize)
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(holder.tvAttachment);
        holder.tvAttachment.setMinimumHeight(thumbSize);



        setupGridView(view, holder);


    }



    private void setupGridView(View view, final ViewHolder holder) {
        /*final ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_inventory_products_griditems_attachment);
        com.rey.material.widget.Button btMore = (com.rey.material.widget.Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_inventory_products_griditems_More);
        com.rey.material.widget.Button btPlus = (com.rey.material.widget.Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_inventory_products_griditems_addOne);
//final TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_inventory_products_griditems_Title);
        final RialTextView tvPrice = (RialTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_inventory_products_griditems_Price);
        final TextView tvItemId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_inventory_products_griditems_ItemId);
        final TextView tvGuId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_inventory_products_griditems_GuId);
        //final TextView tvRemain = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_inventory_products_griditems_Remain);*/


        holder.tvAttachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                       /* BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable());*/
                showImageDialog(holder.itemGuId);

            }
        });

        holder.btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                        /*addToInvoiceDialog(tvTitle.getText().toString(), tvPrice.getText().toString(), tvItemId.getText().toString(),
                                            tvRemain.getText().toString(),iv.getDrawable(),tvGuId.getText().toString());*/
                showAddToInvoiceFragment(holder.itemId, holder.priceDef);
            }
        });

        holder.btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //InventoryFragment.AddToInvoice(holder.itemId, 1, holder.priceDef, null, null);
            }
        });

    }



    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private void showImageDialog(String ReferenceGuId) {

        //InventoryFragment.openAlbum(ReferenceGuId);

    }

    private void showAddToInvoiceFragment(String itemId, String priceDef) {
        //InventoryFragment.showAddToInvoiceFragment(itemId, priceDef);
    }


}
```

this is the part in my java code where I set the adapter:

```
ShygunInventoryGridCursorAdapter listAdapter1 = new ShygunInventoryGridCursorAdapter(context,cursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
                gridView.setNumColumns(colCount);
                gridView.setAdapter(listAdapter1);
```

MAT screen( I could not reach anywhere here, I mean non of roots or ... was my own code)

[image: MAT]
[image: MAT2]

Not to mention, adding `System.gc()` at the end of `get View` method in the adapter will solve everything, but I'm sure it's not the right thing to do

Comment: Use this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260112/android-loading-images-efficient-out-of-memory/31260418#31260418

Comment: @Jigsh thanks, it works way better than the grid view, and honestly it's much simpler, anyway I will be glad to accept your answer, so may I ask you to post it as answer so I can accept it?